# Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

Get this strange error. I am learning javaScript and copy the code from somewhere and run it but get the error. Here is the code. Change the empty string to any other thing like "Test" I will still get the same error.

```
 <script>

    function theAge() {
        var message, x;
        message = document.getElementById("message");
        message.innerHTML = "";
        x = document.getElementById(age).value;
        try {
            x=Number(x);
            if(x=="") throw "is empty";
            if(isNaN(x)) throw "is not a number";
            if(x>10) throw "is too high";
            if(x<5) throw "is too low";
        }
        catch (err) {
            message.innerHTML = "input" + err;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you have a typo here

```
x = document.getElementById(age).value;
```

try

```
x = document.getElementById("age").value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You must have an element for message and one for age in your html. And also put the age term between `""`

[See it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/qhhzmxhy/)

HTML Example:

```
<div>
    Age: <input type="text" id="age" /> </br>
    Message: <div id="message"> </div> </br>
    <button onclick="theAge()">Click</button>
</div>
```

JS code

```
function theAge() {
    var message, x;
    message = document.getElementById("message");
    message.innerHTML = "";
    x = document.getElementById("age").value;
    try {
        x=Number(x);
        if(x=="") throw "is empty";
        if(isNaN(x)) throw "is not a number";
        if(x>10) throw "is too high";
        if(x<5) throw "is too low";
    }
    catch (err) {
        message.innerHTML = "input" + err;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using server control...
use jQuery method

$("#controlID").html();

Answer (score 0):

Add this after the closing curly bracelet of your 'theAge' function...

```
Window.onload = theAge;
```

And make sure your age element is in " ".
This error occurs when your browser reads your js function before your HTML elements...
Alternatively you can move your script tag to the bottom of your body tag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).